# Valgrind memcheck tool showing 0 leaks eventhough there are possible memleaks

Tags: c, memory-leaks, valgrind, compiler-optimization, openwrt

I need to investigate memory leaks in my C project. But before that, i just written a sample program and cross compiled to `ARM-v8-a 64bit OpenWRT` linux platform. With this program, I am trying to understand Valgrind leak report.
Unfortunately with this valgrind run, not seeing any leaks and expecting the memcheck tool to report a leak summary of 50bytes.

**Valgrind tool optimized** : Yes with `-Os(OpenWRT) and -O2(Valgrind Makefile)`
**Binary Optimized** : No
**libc standard used** : `MUSL` OpenWRT ARM 64bit

`Why valgrind is not able to intercept malloc calls eventhough binary executes malloc calls?`

Sample Code:

```
char *ptr = NULL;
printf("Doing memory alloc\n");
ptr = malloc(50);
if (!ptr) {
    printf("Malloc failure\n");
    return -1;
}
printf("Malloc returned : %p\n", (void *)ptr);
memset(ptr, 0, 50);
strcpy(ptr, "Valgrind leak Analysis!!!\n");
printf("%s\n", ptr);
return 0;
```

Valgrind  output:

```
==481==
--481-- Valgrind options:
--481--    --tool=memcheck
--481--    --leak-check=full
--481--    --show-leak-kinds=all
--481--    --track-origins=yes
--481--    --verbose
--481--    --default-suppressions=no
--481-- Contents of /proc/version:
--481--   Linux version 5.4.164 (renv@bbd-svr-ubt20-004) (gcc version 7.5.0 (OpenWrt GCC 7.5.0 r11-afafb2b1c)) #0 SMP PREEMPT Mon Jun 5 15:00:29 2023
--481--
--481-- Arch and hwcaps: ARM64, LittleEndian, baseline
--481-- Page sizes: currently 4096, max supported 65536
--481-- Valgrind library directory: /usr/lib/valgrind
--481-- Reading syms from /home/superadmin/leaks
--481-- Scheduler: using generic scheduler lock implementation.


Doing memory alloc
Malloc returned : 0x40945e0
Valgrind leak Analysis!!!

==481==
==481== HEAP SUMMARY:
==481==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==481==   total heap usage: 0 allocs, 0 frees, 0 bytes allocated
==481==
==481== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==481==
==481== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

**Below are my Binary and valgrind file type info:**

```
root@Bean10:/home/superadmin# file leaks
leaks: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, ARM aarch64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-musl-aarch64.so.1, with debug_info, not stripped
root@Bean10:/home/superadmin#
root@Bean10:/home/superadmin# file /usr/bin/valgrind
/usr/bin/valgrind: ELF 64-bit LSB pie executable, ARM aarch64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-musl-aarch64.so.1, no section header
root@Bean10:/home/superadmin#
root@Bean10:/home/superadmin# ls /usr/lib/valgrind/
64bit-core-valgrind-s1.xml         64bit-linux-valgrind-s2.xml        memcheck-arm64-linux
64bit-core-valgrind-s2.xml         64bit-linux.xml                    none-arm64-linux
64bit-core.xml                     default.supp                       vgpreload_core-arm64-linux.so
64bit-linux-valgrind-s1.xml        leaks                              vgpreload_memcheck-arm64-linux.so
root@Bean10:/home/superadmin#
```

**Compilation command used:**

Please note this is the cross toolchain compiler used in my project. How to check does this implicitly uses optimization flag.

```
aarch64-openwrt-linux-musl-gcc -g leaks.c
```

Compiler Version Details:

```
aarch64-openwrt-linux-musl-gcc (OpenWrt GCC 7.5.0 r11-afafb2b1c) 7.5.0
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

**Symbol info from object file:**
nm shows *malloc* and few other funcs as *undefined* symbol.

```
$ aarch64-openwrt-linux-musl-nm leaks.o
0000000000000000 T main
                 U malloc
                 U memset
                 U printf
                 U puts

$ aarch64-openwrt-linux-musl-strings -a leaks.o
Doing memory alloc
Malloc failure
Malloc returned : %p
Valgrind leak Analysis!!!
GCC: (OpenWrt GCC 7.5.0 r11-afafb2b1c) 7.5.0
leaks.c
main
puts
malloc
printf
memset
.symtab
.strtab
.shstrtab
.rela.text
.data
.bss
.rodata
.comment
.note.GNU-stack
$
```

**objdump output having text and PLT section:**

```
$ aarch64-openwrt-linux-musl-objdump -D leaks
```

Disassembly of section .plt:

```
.....
0000000000400530 <malloc@plt>:
  400530:   b0000090    adrp    x16, 411000 <printf>
  400534:   f9400a11    ldr x17, [x16, #16]
  400538:   91004210    add x16, x16, #0x10
  40053c:   d61f0220    br  x17

0000000000400540 <memset@plt>:
  400540:   b0000090    adrp    x16, 411000 <printf>
  400544:   f9400e11    ldr x17, [x16, #24]
  400548:   91006210    add x16, x16, #0x18
  40054c:   d61f0220    br  x17
```

Disassembly of section .text:

```
......
000000000040060c <main>:
  40060c:   a9be7bfd    stp x29, x30, [sp, #-32]!
  400610:   910003fd    mov x29, sp
  400614:   f9000fbf    str xzr, [x29, #24]
  400618:   90000000    adrp    x0, 400000 <_init-0x4d8>
  40061c:   911b0000    add x0, x0, #0x6c0
  400620:   97ffffc0    bl  400520 <puts@plt>
  400624:   d2800640    mov x0, #0x32                   // #50
  400628:   97ffffc2    bl  400530 <malloc@plt>
  40062c:   f9000fa0    str x0, [x29, #24]
  400630:   f9400fa0    ldr x0, [x29, #24]
  400634:   f100001f    cmp x0, #0x0
  400638:   540000c1    b.ne    400650 <main+0x44>  // b.any
  40063c:   90000000    adrp    x0, 400000 <_init-0x4d8>
  400640:   911b6000    add x0, x0, #0x6d8
  400644:   97ffffb7    bl  400520 <puts@plt>
  400648:   12800000    mov w0, #0xffffffff             // #-1
  40064c:   14000016    b   4006a4 <main+0x98>
  400650:   90000000    adrp    x0, 400000 <_init-0x4d8>
  400654:   911ba000    add x0, x0, #0x6e8
  400658:   f9400fa1    ldr x1, [x29, #24]
  40065c:   97ffffad    bl  400510 <printf@plt>
  400660:   d2800642    mov x2, #0x32                   // #50
  400664:   52800001    mov w1, #0x0                    // #0
  400668:   f9400fa0    ldr x0, [x29, #24]
  40066c:   97ffffb5    bl  400540 <memset@plt>
  400670:   f9400fa2    ldr x2, [x29, #24]
  400674:   90000000    adrp    x0, 400000 <_init-0x4d8>
  400678:   911c0001    add x1, x0, #0x700
  40067c:   aa0203e0    mov x0, x2
  400680:   a9400c22    ldp x2, x3, [x1]
  400684:   a9000c02    stp x2, x3, [x0]
  400688:   f9400822    ldr x2, [x1, #16]
  40068c:   f9000802    str x2, [x0, #16]
  400690:   b8417021    ldur    w1, [x1, #23]
  400694:   b8017001    stur    w1, [x0, #23]
  400698:   f9400fa0    ldr x0, [x29, #24]
  40069c:   97ffffa1    bl  400520 <puts@plt>
  4006a0:   52800000    mov w0, #0x0                    // #0
  4006a4:   a8c27bfd    ldp x29, x30, [sp], #32
  4006a8:   d65f03c0    ret
```

**How Valgrind compiled**
Valgrind is built with below optimization and hardening options.

```
-O2 -g -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wcast-align -Wcast-qual -Wwrite-strings -Wempty-body -Wformat -Wformat-signedness -Wformat-security -Wignored-qualifiers -Wmissing-parameter-type -Wlogical-op -Wimplicit-fallthrough=2 -Wold-style-declaration -finline-functions -fno-stack-protector -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-builtin  -O2 -Os -pipe -march=armv8-a -mcpu=cortex-a73+crypto -fno-caller-saves -fno-plt -Wa,--noexecstack -fhonour-copts -Wno-error=unused-but-set-variable -Wno-error=unused-result -iremap/home/renv/BBD_R2302OpenWrtB/working/QSDK12/qsdk/build_dir/target-aarch64/valgrind-3.15.0:valgrind-3.15.0 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wl,-z,now -Wl,-z,relro
```

Expecting some help/directions to proceed further.

Comment: There is a good chance that your `malloc` is optimized out.

Comment: Likely, the compiler is optimizing your code to remove the `malloc` because `ptr` is never used. So you've basically compiled a NOOP program that simply returns 0.

Comment: "Does presence of optimization wouldn't reveal any leaks. Kindly confirm.
Expecting some help/directions to proceed further." - I don't quite understand what you are asking. Generally speaking, compiler optimizations are a _good thing_. Your question is about why valgrind isn't reporting memory leaks in the provided code, to which we've arrived at a reasonable conclusion. However, I understand you may have memory leaks in your actual program that you'd like to resolve. That may be best suited for a new question with the relevant code to reproduce the leak.

Comment: Sorry for deviating from the actual ask. I have updated the code in which ptr is used now. Shall you please check the assembler now. Because i am still seeing no leaks in valgrind.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica - Oh sorry, Its a typo. Expecting 50bytes leak.

Comment: @renga_in_stack Your updated code still reduces to `printf("Valgrind leak Analysis!!!\n\n");`, so the call of `malloc()` can still be optimized away.  If you add something like `printf( "malloc() returned %p\n", ( void * ) ptr );` to your code, your compiler will not be able to remove the call to `malloc()`.

Comment: -O0 should help to do investigations

Comment: @AndrewHenle - Ok I printed Malloc return address. But still no leaks. I have updated the code and valgrind output in Description section. Also I didn't use any optimisation flags like -O1, -O2, -O3 or -Os explicitly.

Comment: @renga_in_stack Can you run `gcc -c leaks.c -o leaks.o` and then run tools such as `nm` or even `strings -a` on `leaks.o` and see if there are actually calls to `malloc()` in the resulting object file?

Comment: @AndrewHenle - Both nm and strings shows malloc. Updated in the description. Kindly comment on it.

Comment: @renga_in_stack I'd say it's possible that you may have found a bug in Valgrind.  You have a definite memory leak in your code, and the object file your compiler creates certainly looks to be calling `malloc()` - and there's no other apparent code that would cause a call to `malloc()`.

Comment: To see if `malloc()` is being used, debug your exe with `gdb`, You can also use ` --trace-malloc=yes` (don't do that with large/long running apps). That will sho all allocation/dealocation calls, but also note that there will be some from libc initialization as well as you own calls.

Comment: You probably need to debug Valgrind itself. You can start with `--trace-redir=yes`.

Comment: @renga_in_stack `nm` just shows entries in the Symbol Table. A Symbol Table entry doesn't imply that the imported functions are actually used in the binary. This is just meta information for the linker and loader. `strings` is finding the `malloc` entry in the symbol table as well.

Comment: The `U` entry in the `nm` output is saying that `malloc`, `memset`, and other functions don't have a defined address in the binary and their addresses be resolved during runtime. That's because those functions come from `stdlib.h`, which your loader will dynamically load when you execute the application. The Linker needs the symbol table to know which functions to map in the GOT/PLT. This is all standard and a separate process than optimizing the assembly produced by the compiler.

Comment: @renga_in_stack if you want to know for certain if the program actually calls malloc, run `objdump -D <binary_name>`, look for where the `main` function is defined in assembly, and see if `malloc` was included in your portion of the code. Feel free to post the assembly here.

Comment: @h0r53 - Please find the updated objdump details in description and I was observing ``malloc``, ``memset`` in the dump. Kindly comment if you need more details.

Comment: @renga_in_stack, thanks for providing the assembly. That was the only way to truly know if the program called `malloc` or not. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: @renga_in_stack Does the system you're running on have an `ldd` utility you can use to see if the file might be statically-linking `libc`?  Or a `file` utility that you can run and add the output to your question?

Comment: @AndrewHenle - I have updated `file` info already for both my binary and valgrind. But both are dynamically linked only. I will update output of dynamic linker output also shortly.

Comment: @AndrewHenle - Please find the update on 'how valgrind compiled' section for your reference. The tool is optimized with `-Os`. Could you please comment on the behavior of  optimized valgrind running non-optimized binary?

Comment: Assuming Valgrind itself isn't buggy, compiling it with optimization or not shouldn't matter.  It's a program that manipulates data, which just happens to be another running program.  If written correctly, building Valgrind with optimization shouldn't change the observable effects (output and stuff it does to the program under test).  The only thing that should matter is how your own code was compiled.  So the details about valgrind build options should be a footnote at best, not mentioned first.  Oh, but I see your question is actually asking if optimized valgrind is ok.  Yes, it is.

Comment: @PeterCordes - Thanks for giving clarifications on the optimized valgrind part. From the symbol table and objdump output of binary, we are seeing ``malloc`` is getting hit but Valgrind is not intercepting memory allocator APIs. Do you have any feedback on this?

Comment: No idea.  Does it ever detect any memory leaks?  Like, can you test that Valgrind isn't totally broken in your MUSL setup?  Perhaps with a longer-running program that leaks memory from multiple calls to malloc?  And that allocates multiple pages of memory, in case that matters, like if `malloc` was internally only moving the `brk` within a single page.

Comment: @PeterCordes - Yes, its not detecting leaks even with a large application which has ``malloc`` calls in multiple places.

Answer (score 5):

It is likely that the `malloc` is being removed through an optimization because your `ptr` variable is never used.

Here is the assembly produced by ARM64 gcc 13.1 (linux) when giving the `-O3` optimize flag. As you can see, the `malloc` call is removed.

```
.LC0:
        .string "Doing memory alloc"
main:
        stp     x29, x30, [sp, -16]!
        adrp    x0, .LC0
        add     x0, x0, :lo12:.LC0
        mov     x29, sp
        bl      puts
        mov     w0, 0
        ldp     x29, x30, [sp], 16
        ret
```

**UPDATE**

The OP has provided the disassembly of the binary, which shows the call for `malloc(50)`, indicating the program actually was compiled without optimizations and the OP could very well have identified a bug in valgrind. I'm leaving my answer for reference in case someone comes across a similar issue in the future and the culprit was compiler optimizations.

Comment: Thanks for the quick update. I didnt use any optim flag. But how to check the cross compiler I used implicitly uses any optimization techniques. Also I just modified the code. Shall you please take a look into it.

Comment: What cross compiler are you using? Do you happen to have a compiler command or Makefile?

Comment: This is ARMv8 -64bit openWRT platform compiler. Updated the command in Description for your reference.

Comment: @h0r53 *It is likely that the malloc is being removed through an optimization...* I had thought so, too, but the OP's latest information shows the object file has references to `malloc()` in it.  ????

Comment: @AndrewHenle the OP's latest information suggests that the binary has a symbol for malloc in the symbol table. That's most likely because the symbol table and initial linker information was generated before optimizations to the code itself. But that doesn't mean the definition of `main` uses `malloc`. _It's never called_ isn't the same thing as _it's not included in the binary_.

Comment: @h0r53 OP states "I didnt use any optimization flag for compilation."  So no, [the linker didn't optimize anything](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-7.5.0/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#Optimize-Options): "When producing the final binary, GCC only applies link-time optimizations to those files that contain bytecode."  N.B. OP is using GCC 7.5.  Conclusions from using GCC 13.1 are not relevant.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I believe the original question either mentioned ARM64 gcc 13.1 or the latest gcc for ARM64. The question has been updated and expanded over the past few days. Either way - there is no point in guess work. If the OP wants to know if malloc was optimized out of their code or if there is a Valgrind error, they need to provide the assembly of the binary with a tool such as `objdump`. Until that happens, we won't know for certain.

Comment: @h0r53 - Please find the Assembler section of binary updated as well in description

Comment: @renga_in_stack, thank you for providing the assembly for the binary. Indeed, the assembly shows the call to `malloc(50)`. That suggests that the program actually does call malloc and for whatever reason, valgrind isn't reporting the memory leak.

Comment: @h0r53  Hmm, statically-linked, perhaps, so Valgrind can't intercept the call?

Comment: @h0r53- Thanks for confirming that `malloc` getting called. i just searched valgrind community forum in that similar issue reported for ARM platform https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=469565

Comment: @h0r53 - Though my binary is not optimized, `valgrind` tool whatever I used is optimized with `-Os` flag and is part of `OpenWRT` build environment. I have updated the question with GCC optimization, hardening options used. Do you have any comments on the tool part?

Comment: @renga_in_stack I don't think the executable is statically linked. The `0` / `U` addresses shown in your `nm` output suggest that `stdlib` is dynamically linked.

Comment: @h0r53 - I was using `MUSL` libc standard C library with the program interpreter as `/lib/ld-musl-aarch64.so.1`. Are you seeing any gaps here. Because in `GLIBC` along with X86_64 linux environment, Valgrind reveals the leak for the same sample code.

Comment: Ahh yes, well I think a large part of this interesting issue may be related to the use of `aarch64-openwrt`. Perhaps that environment is re/cross-compiling for the ARM architecture, and you've already pointed out the aarch64 Valgrind build uses the `-02` flag. It's the most likely cause of your issue. Another approach would be to find a native ARM host, compile the code, check the assembly (for inclusion of `malloc`), then use the native ARM version of Valgrind to check for leaks.

Comment: We are somewhere between the issue being related to cross compilation (and whatever implicit compilation flags are used therein) and a potential bug in valgrind. My intuition says the issue is related to cross compilation and hidden implicit optimizations that were made during that process.