# What factors increases VmRSS of a process in linux

Tags: c, linux, memory-management, heap-memory, virtual-memory

I come across a situation in my project in which `VmRSS` of my application increases in irregular intervals. In the background there are Heap memory allocations using `malloc/calloc/realloc` calls and deallocations with `free` also happening frequently.
During the long run stability tests, VmRSS almost consumes much of `RAM` memory space and finally the system reboots with lack of memory space.

Is there any way to monitor and instrument my application to control virtual memory usage?
Also any approach to find which section of the code causes the problem?
Is it possible to swap out virtual memory mapping from real RAM to disk?

Comment: Did you run valgrind already?

Comment: @infinitezero - I tried valgrind but it is not intercepting `malloc` calls. Already a SO qn in https://stackoverflow.com/q/76467215/4036405

Comment: Can you show some code ?